# Upgardation of Firebase Old version to New Version

Tags: firebase

I have created a Firebase account few months ago which is in Old version to develop an android app.

Later for some reason, i want to change the account for that application again which is allowing us to create newer version and this is not supported by the existing developed application.

Is it possible to create a firebase account in older version now? Or is there any method to upgrade the codes which will support newer version?

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer possible to create accounts in the legacy Firebase console (on firebase.com). It will also [soon be impossible to create new projects in the legacy Firebase console](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Be9NJQVNEP8).

It **is** possible to upgrade your existing project to the new Firebase console (firebase.google.com) and to upgrade your code to the new Firebase SDKs. Both are covered in the migration guides for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios), [web](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android).